# How can I replace an Option within a Vec?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Here's the code (I also put it in a playpen here: http://is.gd/f9O3YG):

```
use std::mem;

pub struct Tree {
    children: Vec<Option<Box<Tree>>>,
    // other fields
}

impl Tree {
    pub fn mutate(&mut self, x: i64) {
        if self.is_base_case() {
            // base case
            unimplemented!();
        } else {
            // recursive case
            let idx: usize = unimplemented!();
            let mut subtree: Option<&mut Box<Tree>> = self.children.get_mut(idx).expect("child idx out of bounds").as_mut();
            match subtree {
                Some(ref mut subtree) => unimplemented!(),
                None => {
                    let mut new_tree = Tree::new();
                    // recurse on the new tree here
                    mem::replace(&mut subtree, Some(&mut Box::new(new_tree)));
                },
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn new() -> Tree {
        unimplemented!();
    }

    fn is_base_case(&self) -> bool {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("it compiled!");
}
```

I'm writing a data structure which is a type of tree. It stores its subtrees in a `Vec<Option<Box<Tree>>>`, since it's not guaranteed to have a subtree in every position. I'm trying to write a method which mutates the tree, possibly creating one of the subtrees if it doesn't exist.

As you can see if you try to run the code in the playpen, my approach doesn't work. I'm not sure what the error message is telling me - my best guess is that it wants the newly created subtree to have the same lifetime as the subtree created on line 14, in order for the replacement to be safe. However, I'm not sure how to make it have that lifetime. It also made me think: since the new subtree will also need to be valid for the entire lifetime of the data structure, shouldn't it have the same lifetime as the parent tree? It might need to be shorter though, since there are other methods which can remove subtrees (I'm using `Option::take` for that, which works well enough - I checked the documentation for an opposite of that and couldn't find one). Is my approach flawed, and if not, how should I fix my implementation?

Comment: you were simply using too many references everywhere ;) get rid of them and do everything by value and you are fine: http://is.gd/xv3GHi

Comment: @ker Won't that prevent the `mem::replace` from doing its job?

Comment: @ker Wow, I was really overthinking this. Can you make that an answer?

Comment: @ker Actually, that has a side effect of removing the tree in the case that it already exists, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't see why you need `mem::replace`. if you ignore the result of `replace`, you might as well simply assign...

Comment: @zrneely: yes this removes it from the tree, you need to put it back later. The solution space is very large here, not sure what the idiomatic way would be here.

Comment: @ker I'd assume that it's used in the elided parts of the code, but as it stands `*subtree = Some(...)` would be more effective. That said, a borrow still seems much more straightforward than temporary removal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to put an `&mut` inside some structure which lives longer than the thing `&mut` is pointing to. Here's a reduced example:

```
use std::mem;

pub struct Tree {
    children: Vec<Option<Box<Tree>>>,
}

impl Tree {
    pub fn mutate(&mut self, x: i64) {
        let idx: usize = unimplemented!();
        let mut subtree: Option<&mut Box<Tree>> =
            self.children.get_mut(idx).unwrap().as_mut();

        let mut new_tree = Tree::new();
        mem::replace(&mut subtree, Some(&mut Box::new(new_tree)));
    }

    pub fn new() -> Tree {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The problem is that `&mut Box::new(...)` is a temporary reference, so you can't just copy it into another structure. Your use of `as_mut` on the `Option` is confusing; if you just *don't* do it your code works fine:

```
let mut subtree: &mut Option<Box<Tree>> =
    self.children.get_mut(idx).unwrap();

let mut new_tree = Tree::new();
mem::replace(subtree, Some(Box::new(new_tree)));
```

[Here's it in the larger context.](http://is.gd/yj0AjO) [You can simplify it a bit, too.](http://is.gd/F1QFsp)